# Setting Mean and Standard Deviation When Not Given Data

Tags: excel, statistics, probability

I am attempting to model independent and identically distributed normal random variables in Excel. In order to perform this take it appears I need to identify the mean and standard deviation but the only data I am given is that the variable exceeds 7.26 95% of the times and 8.02 only 5% of the times.

My attempt to find the mean resulted in 7.64 ( (7.26 + 8.02) / 2)
Using this mean I arrived at an SD at 0.232 through trail and error. Using these figures seems to model the variables correctly but I am wondering is there a way of deducing the correct solution without using trail and error?

Comment: You should ask this on the Stack Exchange Mathematics site.

Comment: In order to find mu and sigma you must solve a system of 2 nonlinear equations, namely `snp(z1 = 0.05)` and `snp(z2 = 0.95)` where z1 = (7.26 - mu)/sigma and z2 = (8.02 - mu)/sigma and snp(z) = (1 + erf(z/sqrt(2)))/2 is the standard normal probability cdf. There are various ways to numerical approximations but these amount to careful guessing schemes. Trial and error is a reasonable way to find approximations.